# How to set div height to equal it div height?

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to know how can I adjust the height of a div depending of the content on it. For example, I have the following HTML:

```css
div.Pantalla {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/11/23/02/plane-841441_1280.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.formulario{
  position: relative;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}

form{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  padding:16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}


.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Add some margins for each label */
.form-inline label {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

/* Style the input fields */
.form-inline input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Style the submit button */
.form-inline button {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #0095dd;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.form-inline button:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}


ul{
  width:100%;
  padding:16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li{
  position: center;
  width:100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

.column button{
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #0095dd;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.column button:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Pantalla">

<div class="formulario">
  <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="SearchForm">
    <input type="text" id="Origin"  placeholder="Enter Origin" formControlName="Origin">
    <input type="text" id="Destiny" placeholder="Enter Destination" formControlName="Destiny">
    <input type="date" id="CheckIn" placeholder="Enter Check-In Date" formControlName="CheckIn">
    <input type="date" id="Checkout" placeholder="Enter Check-Out Date" formControlName="Checkout">
    <input type="number" id="people" placeholder="Enter Number of People" formControlName="people">
    <button type="submit" (click)="getPacks()">Go!</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="column menu">
     <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let pack of packs; let i = index">
       <li class="list-group-item">Flight {{pack.flight.Airline}}, {{pack.flight.LandMarkName_Origin}} - {{pack.flight.LandMarkName_Destination}} for {{pack.flight.minPrice}} Dolars </li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Stay at {{pack.hotel.name}}, with {{pack.hotel.Star_rating}} / {{pack.hotel.scale}} Stars</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Visit
         <p *ngFor="let places of pack.places; let j = index">{{places.name}}, </p>
       </li>
       <button>Get it!</button>
     </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

However, when I launch my application, what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AJLt.png):

I want that the height of the "Pantalla" div equals the total height of the divs that it has. How can I achieve this?

UPDATED: When the code is like this, what I get is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkPRg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the background only cover to the first div is that you're missing the **display rule**.

Please add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction:column`, then you will see it's working.

```css
div.Pantalla {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/11/23/02/plane-841441_1280.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  /* Add this */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.formulario{
  position: relative;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}

form{
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  padding:16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}


.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Add some margins for each label */
.form-inline label {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

/* Style the input fields */
.form-inline input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Style the submit button */
.form-inline button {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #0095dd;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.form-inline button:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}


ul{
  width:100%;
  padding:16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li{
  position: center;
  width:100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

.column button{
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #0095dd;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.column button:hover {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Pantalla">

<div class="formulario">
  <form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="SearchForm">
    <input type="text" id="Origin"  placeholder="Enter Origin" formControlName="Origin">
    <input type="text" id="Destiny" placeholder="Enter Destination" formControlName="Destiny">
    <input type="date" id="CheckIn" placeholder="Enter Check-In Date" formControlName="CheckIn">
    <input type="date" id="Checkout" placeholder="Enter Check-Out Date" formControlName="Checkout">
    <input type="number" id="people" placeholder="Enter Number of People" formControlName="people">
    <button type="submit" (click)="getPacks()">Go!</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="column menu">
     <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let pack of packs; let i = index">
       <li class="list-group-item">Flight {{pack.flight.Airline}}, {{pack.flight.LandMarkName_Origin}} - {{pack.flight.LandMarkName_Destination}} for {{pack.flight.minPrice}} Dolars </li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Stay at {{pack.hotel.name}}, with {{pack.hotel.Star_rating}} / {{pack.hotel.scale}} Stars</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Visit
         <p *ngFor="let places of pack.places; let j = index">{{places.name}}, </p>
       </li>
       <button>Get it!</button>
     </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want it height to be the same as the "sum" of the heights of the div inside it. So, basically, what I want is that the height of Pantallas, and it background, cover both the searcher (as it is doing at the moment) and the column menu div when it is displayed.

Comment: Do I need to add this to Pantalla block in the CSS, right?

Comment: Yes, please add it into the CSS of div.Pantalla

Comment: It is not working. Check the edited question to see the new output.

Comment: That´s the result if I execute it into my server.

Comment: You might clean the cache on your server, the **display rule** do make the tricks, it's even working on the code snippet. If the problem still exist, it will mean that the problem is caused by other factors which need further inspection.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you have a main div and two child div inside that main div element
and you want that the background image of must cover both div.
if I am right then change the height of your main element

```
height: 100vh;
```

change your css code like below and see what happend

```
div.Pantalla {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/11/23/02/plane-841441_1280.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: That way, it will do exactly the same as I used to have. The new div will go out of the height of the father div.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the image that occupies all the space that its parent has, try this:
I suppose that the div.Pantalla's parent is a div with id: app.

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
div.Pantalla {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

}